# Can A Shortcode Get HTML/Text From Content And Return It Twice With Added HTML?

Tags: php, shortcode, slideshow

I'm trying to cut down on some work for myself and I was hoping someone might know if this is possible.

These are images setup in a slider that shows a text overlay on the image on the next slide in a multi-page post.

Here's what I'm trying to do.  Take this:

```
<h2>Image Title</h2>
[caption]<img src="http">[/caption]
text for slide
```

And output them like this:

```
<div class="singe_slide">
<h2>Image Title</h2>
[caption]<img src="http">[/caption]
</div>
<!--nextpage-->
<div class="singe_slide">
<h2>Image Title</h2>  //Same Image Next Page
[caption]<img src="http">[/caption]
<div class="slide_caption"><div class="captExt">
text for slide
</div></div>
<!--nextpage-->
```

This is what I'm currently using for my shortcodes but it takes just as long to just manually add the div's and it's very messy.  It looks like this:

```
[Slide]<h2>Image Title</h2>
[caption]<img src="http">[/caption][/Slide]
<!--nextpage-->
[Slide]<h2>Image Title</h2> //Same Image Next Page
[caption]<img src="http">[/caption]
[SlideCap]text for slide[/SlideCap][/Slide]
<!--nextpage-->
```

And these are my 2 shortcodes:

```
function Slide($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = wpautop(trim($content));
    return '<div class="singe_slide">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('Slide', 'Slide');

function SlideCap($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = wpautop(trim($content));
   return '<div class="slide_caption"><div class="captExt">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('SlideCap', 'SlideCap');
```

I'm open to suggestions on an easier way to do this.  This is my very first shortcode so I'm new to it.

Is it possible to get something between shortcodes as a variable?
[shortcode]This Part Here[/shortcode]

Comment: I don't think I quite understand. The second argument in your shortcode handler - $content - will get the content that is between your shortcodes. Is that what you mean? I'm not sure why you're running this through do_shortcode() again...

Comment: @TimMalone I added more info to the post that might help.  First off I'm not a php programmer so a lot of this is just trial and error.  I ran it twice because I have a shortcode within a shortcode and I don't know how else to do it.  I added how I write my shortcode currently when doing a post in WP.  I'm trying to return the heading and image twice with a nextpage separating it and the text once on the second page all wrapped in div's.

Comment: What isn't clear in your question is what html output you are trying to achieve. You've shared lots of code, but you haven't said "I have this shortcode X and I want it to produce this html Y. This code Z is what I am trying to use to make it, but instead its producing W. Why is that?"

Comment: @AntonChanning Bare with me, I'm not a programmer.  I put up what I'm trying to achieve and what I am currently doing to achieve it.  The problem is it's very tedious to add all of the shortcodes and heading/images twice.  It's just as time consuming as putting in the html myself instead of shortcodes too.  What I want to do is make it so my shortcode takes the $content and outputs it the way I want.  Essentially combining my shortcodes into one.  I just don't know how to get each item I need in between the shortcodes and output it the way I want.  Do I need to split it into an array first?

Comment: I have a programmer working on it now.  If he can do it I'll post up what he did.

Comment: So, are you trying to use a shortcode to create an image with a caption?

Comment: Are you actually looking for something more like `[slide=http://image.url]<h2>Image title</h2>[slidecap]This is the caption.[/slidecap][/slide]`?

Comment: @AntonChanning  Sorry if I'm confusing you on this.  The caption is from wordpress not to be confused with the SlideCap shortcode.  The caption is inserted automatically when I add it to the caption field for the image where I put in the image credit.  The SlideCap is an opaque overlay on the image with text describing the image.  If I use [slide=http://image.url] that would create even more steps.  I'm trying to take the h2 title, the image with or without the caption, and the post text and post back the h2 title and image on one page then the h2 title, image, and post text on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've figured out what you're actually asking. You're asking what the variable for the bit between the shortcodes. If that is all you are asking, then the answer is the parameter variable `$content`. You are already processing it in your code.

Also, in your example, you seem to have a third shortcode, `[caption]` that you aren't processing. Is that deliberate? It doesn't look like you really want to produce final html with that in, so this solution assumes you don't want that.

I'm going to assume that what you want is a simple to use shortcode format such as:

```
[slide=ImageTitle][slideimg]http://some.domain/slide.jpg[/slideimg][slidecap]This is the caption.[/slidecap][/slide]
```

Which you can then process simply by adjusting your functions like so:

```
function shortcode_slide($atts, $content = null) {
    if(empty($atts)) {
        $img_title='';
    } else {
        // [slide=Title]...[/slide]
        // [slide="Multi word title"]...[/slide]
        $atts = $this->attributefix( $atts );
        $img_title = '<h2>'.trim(array_shift($atts),'="').'</h2>'; //Remove quotes and equals.
    }

    $content = wpautop(trim($content));
    return '<div class="singe_slide">'.$img_title. do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('slide', 'shortcode_slide');

function shortcode_slidecap($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = wpautop(trim($content));
    return '<div class="slide_caption"><div class="captExt">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('slidecap', 'shortcode_slidecap');

function shortcode_slideimg($atts, $content = null) {
    $content = wpautop(trim($content));
    return '<img src="'.$content.'" />';
}
add_shortcode('slideimg', 'shortcode_slideimg');
```

This should produce working html.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'll try it out tomorrow and see if I can get it to work.